# xubuntu does not recognize built in WebCamMacBook 2006

Tags: drivers, webcam, cheese, ubuntu-drivers

I installed xubuntu on my MacBook from 2006 and I cant get the webcam to work. I used cheese and it says device not found

Comment: are you using the 64-bit Mac version of xubuntu?

Comment: No, Laptop had 500mb or ram when I install it I now have 2GB

Comment: maybe that's the problem, for a macbook you should use a Mac-Version of ubuntu. Maybe you could get an inofficial i386 Mac version?

Comment: [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/) you can get a fitting version of 12.04 LTS, wich is not Xubuntu